# Is there a way to remove front dot evaluation in golang html/template

Tags: ruby, parsing, go, templates, mustache

I have a set of templates which needs to be rendered both in ruby and golang.
I was looking at golang "html/template" , it renders template in format {{.myname}} but ruby mustache parser takes {{myname}} https://github.com/mustache/mustache .
Is there any way so that golang html/template also renders {{myname}} i.e without dot. Or anyother library in ruby which behaves similar to "html/template" in golang

Also have a requirement of changing delimeter from {{}} to [[]] so cant use https://github.com/aymerick/raymond

Have a requirement of custom function so cant use https://github.com/cbroglie/mustache

Comment: You can change the [delimiters](https://golang.org/pkg/html/template/#Template.Delims), but you can't remove the dot. The dot has a special meaning and removing it would create conflicts with other non-dot-prefixed constructs that the template engine supports.

Answer (score 3):

If you want the same template to be rendered using two different programming languages, you need to use a template language which has implementations for both those programming languages.

As luck would have it, the Mustache template language has implementations for both Ruby and Go, so you could use Mustache as your template language, and a [Go implementation](https://github.com/cbroglie/mustache).

Comment: But I do have a requirement of custom mustache functions too like processSomething() which wont be called from any object  https://github.com/aymerick/raymond#helper-parameters but would be called directly. Cbroglie does not allow that

Answer (score 2):

Delimeters can be changed in Go templates (see the [`Template.Delims()`](https://golang.org/pkg/html/template/#Template.Delims) method), but the dot `.` has a special meaning, initially it denotes the parameter (pipeline) passed to the template execution, which often changes (certain actions change it like `{{range}}` or `{{with}}`). Quoting from [`text/template`](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/):

> Templates are executed by applying them to a data structure. [...] Execution of the template walks the structure and sets the cursor, represented by a period '.' and called "dot", to the value at the current location in the structure as execution proceeds.

So it impractical the least, and it's not even possible to "elimitate" the dots.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way so that golang html/template also renders {{myname}} i.e without dot.

No.